# Get Status from PHP /w two ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax

Given two api endpoints in my php backend:

Long Function Endpoint: `/_api/_long_function` &
Status Endpoint: `/_api/_status_long_function`

In the `LongFunction` I write session data and in `StatusFunction` I read them and output them in json. I think it is not relevant to the question but I could show the session getting and setting as well if needed.

I now wanted to start the long function with an ajax call and then periodically request the status with a second ajax call.

#### The JS Code

```
$(document).on("click", "#submitSummoner", function () {

    ...INIT VARS...

    /**
     * Periodically check Session Status
     */
    var to,
        clearTime = false,
        called = 0,
        set_delay = 1000,
        callout = function () {
            console.log('Called SessionCheck ' + called);
            $.get($url_session, {
                my_data: my_data
            })
                .done(function (response) {
                    if (called === 0) {
                        console.log('Called LongFunction');
                        $.get($url, {
                            my_data, my_data
                        }).done(function (data) {
                            console.log('Finished Request');
                            if (to) {
                                clearTimeout(to);
                                clearTime = true;
                            }
                        }).fail(function () {
                            if (to) {
                                clearTime = true;
                                clearTimeout(to);
                            }
                            console.log('Failed Request');
                        });
                    }
                    called++;
                    // This is the output I need
                    console.log('Current Status: '+response.status);
                })
                .always(function () {
                    if (clearTime === false) {
                        to = setTimeout(callout, set_delay);
                    }
                });
        };

    callout();
});
```

Unfortunately what happens now is this:

#### Console Output

`1: Called SessionCheck 0`

`2: Called LongFunction` (immediately after)

`3: Current Status: Whatever` (immediatley)

`4: Called SessionCheck 1` (immidately)

`LONG PAUSE UNTIL LONG FUNCTION FINISHED`

`5: Current Status: Finished`

after `Finished` the setTimout gets cleared as expected.

But why does the the `setTimeout` not get called every 1000ms altough the long function takes 10000ms+?

It seems like the second SessionCheck waits for the Long Check to finish, I don't know why? Is it possible that the server "hangs", CPU/RAM seem fine during the `longFunction`. Anything else that could "lock" it

*Even it the php session check function crashes, shouldn't the function still try it again after 1000ms?*

Any hint appreciated!

#### Solution

I figured it out, the session wasn't saving properly in the LongFunction: https://codingexplained.com/coding/php/solving-concurrent-request-blocking-in-php

Comment: Isn't it better to use `if (clearTime === false) { to = setTimeout(callout, set_delay);}` inside .done?

Comment: Well, then I'd need it in `.fail` as well, don't I? The clearing of the timer works though...

Comment: Can we confirm that the get with the url session is not hanging after the first execution?

Comment: I'm suggesting the url session get doesn't  crash the 2nd time, but instead perhaps never returns anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've re-written your solution using jQuery promises to simulate the get requests, and it works as you desired.  I believe this proves the issue is on the back-end, that the "short" get request is not resolving the 2nd time.  Please provide the code that resolves that request.

```js
var to,
  clearTime = false,
  called = 0,
  set_delay = 1000,
  callout = function () {
      console.log('Called SessionCheck ' + called);
      
      var shortGet = $.Deferred();
      shortGet
          .done(function () {
              if (called === 0) {
               
                  var longGet = $.Deferred();
                  
                  console.log('Called LongFunction');
                  longGet.done(function (data) {
                      console.log('Finished Request');
                      if (to) {
                          clearTimeout(to);
                          clearTime = true;
                      }
                  }).fail(function () {
                      if (to) {
                          clearTime = true;
                          clearTimeout(to);
                      }
                      console.log('Failed Request');
                  });
                  
                  
                 setTimeout(function() {
                    longGet.resolve();
                 }, 10000);
              }
              called++;
              // This is the output I need
              console.log('Current Status: still going');
          })
          .always(function () {
              if (clearTime === false) {
                  to = setTimeout(callout, set_delay);
              }
          });
     setTimeout(function() {
        shortGet.resolve();
     }, 200);
  };

callout();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out: https://codingexplained.com/coding/php/solving-concurrent-request-blocking-in-php